# Dual Space to a Lie Algebra. Problem from Takhtajan. Finding the center of a Poisson Algebra

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-algebras, quantum-mechanics, dual-spaces

So I am trying to solve Problem 2.19 from the book "Quantum mechanics for mathematicians" by Takhtajan.
The problem is the following:

Let $g$ be a finite-dimensional Lie Algebra with a Lie bracket $[,]$, and let $g^{*}$ be its dual space. For $f,h \in C^\infty(g^{*})$ define
\begin{align*}
\{f,h\}(u) = u([df,dh])
\end{align*}
where $u \in g^{*}$ and $T^{*}_ug^{*} = g$. 
...
Determine the center of $C^\infty(g^{*})$.
The center of $C^\infty(g^{*})$ is
\begin{align*}
\{f \in C^\infty(g^{*}): \{f,h\} = 0  \quad\forall h \in C^\infty(g^{*})\}
\end{align*}
It is also stated that the center does not consist only of locally constant functions.

The following should be true: If $\{f,h\}=0$ then $[df,dh]=0$. But now I don't know how to solve this equation, i.e. finding a function that is not locally constant with this property. 
Thank you for your advice.

Comment: First comment: it is not true that if $\{f,h\} = 0$ then $[df,dh] = 0$. I did not solve it completely, but I took $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{so(3)}$ and I found for instance that $f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ is in the center of $C^{\infty}(\mathfrak{g}^*)$. I know this post is old, but I hope this helps someone somewhere.

Comment: Actually, in the example I took, namely $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{so}(3)$, if $f(x,y,z) = k(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)$, where $k$ is any smooth function from $[0, \infty)$ to $\mathbb{R}$, then $f$ is also in the center of $C^{\infty}(\mathfrak{g}^*)$. I conjecture that any element of the center of $C^{\infty}(\mathfrak{g}^*)$ is of this form, for $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{so}(3)$.